# Show/hide controls in UI for UWP RadDataGrid rows

Tags: xaml, uwp, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a simple Telerik UI for UWP RadDataGrid:

```
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyVM.Items}"
                             SelectedItem="{x:Bind MyVM.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             UserEditMode="None"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             UserGroupMode="Disabled"
                             UserFilterMode="Disabled"
                             GridLinesThickness="1"
                             AlternationStep="2">
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column1" SizeMode="Fixed" Width="200">
                <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Text1}" />
                            <AppBarButton Grid.Column="1" Icon="Edit" Visibility="???" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Prop1" Header="Column1" />
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Prop2" Header="Column2" />
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

`MyVM` is a `ViewModel` of type `MyViewModel` which has properties `Text1`, `Prop1`, and `Prop2`. I'd like to show/hide the `AppBarButton` in the first column dynamically. When the user selects the row by clicking it, I'd like to show the button. When the row is not selected, I'd like to hide the button.

Is there any way in UWP XAML and `RadDataGrid` to accomplish that? I guess I have to bind the `Visibility` property of the button (the question marks in the code) but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to add a `EditVisibility` property to each item:

```
private Visibility _visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
public Visibility EditVisibility
{
   get => _visibility;
   set
   {
       _visibility = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Now, you are already binding the `SelectedItem` property so we plug the functionality into it. Once the user clicks a row, that row becomes selected. That means the `set` block of your `SelectedItem` property will execute.

In the setter you can then first set the `EditVisibility` of the previously selected row to `Collapsed` and set the new row's `Visibility` to `Visible`:

```
set
{
   if ( _selectedItem != null ) _selectedItem.EditVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   _selectedItem = value;
   _selectedItem.EditVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
   NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I had a similar idea, just instead of Visibility I used a Boolean value and a converter. This way my ViewModel was UI-independent. I hoped there was another "pure XAML" solution. If not, I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a completely clean solution without XAML, only theoretically using UWP behaviors, but I am not sure, I will try it :-)

Comment: I used behaviors with UWP but in this case there are not enough. Thanks for your suggestions.